# Array of Comparables, how to print values?

Tags: java, comparable

Long story short, playing around with generics and comparables, having trouble printing out values directly. Here's a simple example

```
class Ideone<Key extends Comparable<Key>>
{
    private Key[] keys = (Key[]) new Comparable[10];
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Ideone<Integer> test = new Ideone();
        test.keys[0] = 3;
        System.out.println(test.keys[0]);
    }
}
```

Error I am getting is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Comparable; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;

Live code example: http://ideone.com/JPfUZw

Answer (score 0):

A `Key` is a `Comparable`, not vice versa. Also, you cannot initialize an array of generic using downcasting.

Fix the code here:

```
private Key[] keys = (Key[]) new Comparable[10];
```

To

```
private Comparable[] keys = new Comparable[10];
```

This will work since `Key` is a `Comparable` and you can store `Comparable`s in `keys` array, so a `Key` can be stored there.

Or pass the class of the generic as argument and use Array.newInstance as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/530289/1065197):

```
Key[] keys;

public Ideone(Class<Key> clazz, int size) {
    keys = (Key[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
}
```